# Creating model that simulates water flowing down crack, then splitting at 'Y' joint?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, network-analyst, route, modelling, waterways

Maybe this is a simple problem, but I've been given a task of simulating how water flows in one line, along a crack, and then hits a 'Y' junction, where half the water flows in each of the split directions.  I'm having trouble imagining how to do this.

I had thought about just creating 2 routes, that diverge at the 'Y' joint.  Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Could you expand on this question to (a) show how it is related to GIS and, more importantly, (b) explain what the inputs and outputs of such a simulation would be? There are potentially many different ways to run such a simulation (and most of them would have nothing to do with GIS: they would be purely hydraulic or statistical models).

Comment: @StuartOrlivsky, Have you seen the Earth Science Stack Exchange: http://earthscience.stackexchange.com/  It may be more suited to this type of question.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I had thought about modeling it like car traffic, so at the 'Y' joint, half the traffic would go through each split branch.  I guess the first question I have is, is possible to create a route in network analyst that, upon reaching a 'Y' joint, can generate travel times for the flows that go through each branch of the 'Y'? So that it would generate two different travel times with one action?  Sorry I think this is a little different from my original question.